# Advantage to using SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

What advantage is there to using SQL Server Reporting Services instead of just using normal reporting through the application ?

I can understand that the data is on the SQL Server so perhaps this is a good place to serve the report from but what are the actual advantages in practice and is it worth converting your app to use Reporting Services?

Comment: "instead of just using normal reporting through the application" - what application? What reporting facilities does this application offer?

Comment: I mean through a reporting component such as crystal or the microsoft.reporting one.

Comment: Crystal is a report designer in much the same way that SSRS is - it is no more or less a reporting component than SSRS.

Comment: One is served from the SQL Server and the other isn't.

Comment: What do you mean, "served"? Both of them can access SQLServer databases.

Comment: @MarkBannister: I mean that with SSRS the reports usually reside on the SQL Server and not with the application, therefore the SQL Server is "serving" the report to potentially many applications instead of each application serving its own reports.

Answer (score 6):

As usual, it depends :-) If your application purpose is only to serve reports based on data from SQL Server 2005/2008 database, then using reporting services could give you this without a need to develop anything (maybe beside creating report definitions).

So what is given by reporting services:

- reports designer (quite easy to use),
- it could handle user    authentication and authorization,
- report subscriptions,
- exporting    reports to various formats (xls, csv, pdf).

This is only excerpt from full functionality of SSRS. I have used them only a little and quite a long time ago, so I could have forgotten something. As I remember MS prepared report viewer controls, which were usable in ASP.NET web sites and windows forms applications.

Additionally to what you have written in question- as far as I remember reporting services do not need to be installed on same server machine as SQL Server.

If reporting is only minor feature of your application and you have only few specified and already implemented reports, then maybe there is no need to use SSRS.

To summarize, in my opinion main advantages of Sql Server Reporting Services are:

- they fullfill most reporting needs without need to develop all those
  features,
- they allow to create easily new reports,
- they fit very well into MS environment and integrate easily with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not all applications include reporting components, and those that do will normally have a limited set of reports available.

With SSRS - or **any** tool for writing your own reports (such as Crystal, Cognos, BIRT, Jasper etc.) - you can report any data from any data source you can access, in pretty much any format you require.

However, you will have to write the reports yourself.