# Rationale behind reporting framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, reporting-services, crystal-reports

In the enterprise world it seems that if you want to display a report, you **have** to use a reporting framework. You name it: Crystal reports, Jasper reports, ActiveReports, SSRS. But I fail to see why, in 2015, you should prefer a reporting framework over generating an HTML page server side. In a .NET application, for example, what is the advantage of using such framework over a simpler approach of using razor to generate an html web page? That page can be then printed to generate a pdf.

It seems to me that there is a perceived difference when the word "report" is mentioned, that for some reasone requires a separate framework.

Of course usually a reporting framework offer additional features, like a report viewer, but in many cases it's used just to generate a pdf. The advantage of using html+css+js over any other proprietary language to describe a report are to me uncountable: more maintainable, easier to read and write, html is a standard understood by anyone, and there is no need to add another piece to the technology stack of your web service.

I understand my question up to now can be seen as not conforming to SO guidelines, so I'll try to make a more precise question rather than a rant against the enterprise world.

### Question

Let's say my use case is to generate a report like this one:

[image]

inside a page or an iframe. What are the advantages of using, say, Crystal Reports or ActiveReports, in an ASP.NET web site instead of using Razor rendering as I do for all the rest of my service? Is there anything I should be more careful when generating reports compared to normal reports? If the bonus I get is that crappy top bar at the top of the page, well, I would gladly get rid of the pain of using a Reporting Framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advantage to using SQL Server Reporting Services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267090/advantage-to-using-sql-server-reporting-services)

Comment: @SébastienSevrin thanks, but that question compares SSRS vs other framework, while this one compares any reporting framework versus html templating generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you generate an HTML page. How are you going to print it? Are you going to pull in a library to do it? What's your strategy for properly styling it and making sure that navigation elements don't end up in the printed report? How are you going to support exporting to Word, Excel, CSV, or PDF?

Reporting tools often take care of those details for you.

---

That said, in my own applications I usually generate PDF's with [Razor PDF](http://nyveldt.com/blog/page/razorpdf) (and I tell people to print the PDF), generate Excel exports with [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), Word documents with [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/), and don't offer CSV as I hate that format. It means I typically have to redo every single report for each format, but I like the control I get over the output.

Comment: Since it's inserted in an iframe, you can print it client side via browser, or, as you said, use something like razorpdf. Let's say it's the only format I need to support. Are there any caveats against simple razor? What really frustrates me is that none of the reporting frameworks I know about are based on html, but use a crappy proprietary xml format and an even more crappier editor. I love html because is really simple, and it's **primary** goal is to write documents, why are reports different from other documents I wonder :)

Comment: @GiacomoTagliabue I'd avoid iframes like the plague if I were you. Like I said, the caveat is that you have to manually build support for exporting to formats that you want.

Comment: Is support for exporting formats the only big drawback you would personally consider as such?

Comment: @GiacomoTagliabue You're asking some really opinionated and broad questions now. There's probably others, it depends on how much importance you place on things. For example, non-devs can use Crystal Reports without too much help, whereas getting them to use Razor and teaching them HTML and CSS is non-trivial.